# Getting "Run-time error - 13: Type Mismatch" message in ms-access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, runtime-error, type-mismatch

I have two forms in access that are running the same code. However while one works fine the other is giving me a `Run-time error - 13: Type Mismatch` message. I'm not sure where the problem is.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rec As Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Datas")

    rec.AddNew
    rec("Quality Checker Name") = Me.Combo106
    rec("Quality Checker ID") = Me.Text15
    rec("QC Level") = Me.Combo90
    rec("Date of QC") = Me.Text21
    rec("Processor Name") = Me.Combo94
    rec("Processor ID") = Me.Text2
    rec("Team Name") = Me.Combo96
    rec("Date of Processing") = Me.Text108
    rec("Property Ref #") = Me.Text35
    rec("Service Charge Date") = Me.Text135
    rec("Portfolio") = Me.Combo32
    rec("Process Name") = Me.Combo38
    rec("Sub Process Name") = Me.Combo40
    rec.Update

    Set rec = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

    Dim msg As Integer
    msg = MsgBox("Do want to close the form", vbYesNo)

    If msg = vbYes Then
        DoCmd.Close
    ElseIf msg = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Can someone please help.

Comment: Which line do you get the error on ? And why use an unbound form for this ? It's  much easier to use a bound form.

Comment: Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Datas"), here i getting error

Comment: Well that would indicate you probably don't have a table or query called Datas then? And why load a complete table into a recordset when all you want to do is add a record. Much more efficient to load an empty recordset `SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE YourTablePrimaryKeyField = 0`

Comment: Maybe ADODB library is upper in References list, and `Dim rec As Recordset` makes `rec` to be ADODB.Recordset, not DAO.Recordset which returned from OpenRecordset.  Try this `Dim rec As DAO.Recordset`

Comment: Thank You so much, Minty. But as i mentioned that, i am new in MS Access, could you please help me out a code to save or record my data in table .... Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you 4dmonster. Let me check.

Comment: Did run your code. No error on line *Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Datas")* when using an existing table. 
However, if one form is working with this code and the other is not, are they using the same database or different ones?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and name the controls on the form according what they contain. Just a guess: `Processor Name` isn't stored in `Combo94` and `Processor ID` isn't stored in `Text2`.